# Not working Angular-UI carousel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a carousel (Angular-UI):

```
    <div id="slides_control">
        <carousel interval="myInterval">
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                </div>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>
```

And slides with interval:

```
$scope.myInterval = 3000;
    $scope.slides = [
        {
            image: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
        },
        {
            image: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
        },
        {
            image: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
        },
        {
            image: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
        }
       ];
```

Also I installed Angular, Angular-UI with help of Yeoman (angular-generator).
I see slider, but buttons on the left and right side not working. When I see in Chrome Dev tools, after clicking I see that buttons working, but slider not change slide. What can I do for fixing this?

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGQPVo but it's not working...

Comment: Are you using exactly the same angular / angular-ui / angular-carousel version ?